# Merging feature branches to release branch instead of trunk

Tags: version-control, merge, feature-branch

I have a question about two source control scenarios, both with feature branches and release branches:

- In scenario 1 feature branches are merged to the trunk.
- In scenario 2 feature branches are merged to the latest release branch.

What are the consequences of scenario 2 compared to scenario 1?

What are the possible advantages and disadvantages of both scenarios?

---

More details of the two scenarios:

- all development is done in feature branches
- branching is always done from the trunk

Scenario 1 (similar to what is described in [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646/do-you-continue-development-in-a-branch-or-in-the-trunk/35690#35690)):

- feature branches are always merged to the **trunk**
- a new release branch is created from the trunk, **when preparations start for a new release**
- after QA and deployment from a release branch, the changes/bugfixes in the release branch are merged to **trunk and newer release branches**
- changes to the trunk are merged to all **feature branches**

Scenario 2:

- feature branches are always merged to the **newest release branch**
- a new release branch is created from the trunk, **when the current release branch no longer accepts new features and preparations start for final release**
- after QA and deployment from a release branch, the changes/bugfixes in the release branch are merged to **trunk**
- changes to the trunk are merged to all **feature branches and the newest release branch**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since branching is all about **isolation** (see "[When should you branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100829/when-should-you-branch/2107672#2107672)), the difference between the 2 scenarios is **the role you want the main branch `trunk` to have**:

- Scenario 2 is more adapted to a **static role**: `trunk` would be the representation of what is in production (and the occasional hot-fixes needed to be merge back to current feature and next-release branch)
- Scenario 1 is more suited for a **dynamic role**: `trunk` is the integration for various feature, release branches being made from there to consolidate the features which will actually be part of the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have any comments on possible advantages or disadvantages of the two?

Comment: @Ole: I prefer Scenario 2 where trunk is always the representation of what is in production and can be used as a starting point for new branches. Merges to trunk are easier (almost no evolutions on trunk), and the very few hotfixes on trunk are small and rare, making the merge back to feature branches not complicated either. Scenario 1 means more and bigger merges.