# How Save Project version .net Without use copy / Paste folder

Tags: .net, save, project

would know if there is a way to save different version of my program without using (Copy folder and Paste it to in Backup Folder).

For example if my program version is 1.0.5 and now i want make some changes(1.0.6), i want be sure that if those changes wasnt so good i could go back to 1.0.5 without copy each times the old folder.

Is there any tool that help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use branches in your code versioning system.

An explanation which is partly a reason you're asking for:

[why use branches in svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557283/why-use-branches-in-svn)

There are tutorials for using them.
These are:

[Subversion branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s02.html)

[Mercurial branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Branch)

Comment: Thanks , googling and searching for mercurial i found a tool for VisualStudio which use tortoiseHG and Mercurial , http://visualhg.codeplex.com/.

Comment: @user1107078: yes, you're right. For personal projects, I guess, this one is personal or by the way small project, `Mercurial` is a best fit, imo. For bigger projects and development team it needs a time to be adupted and understood by all members.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look into some type of version control i'd try
[Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) or
[Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29)

There are multiple free hosting sites that will host your repository of code, you might want to check out [Google Code Hosting](http://code.google.com/hosting/) or [Sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/) if you don't mind your project being open source.

There are lots of resources online to learn about version control, just start Googling.

Might take a bit to setup, but once you got it running it makes things much easier to switch to different branches of code or revert changes, work from multiple computers, ect.