# In SVN, Is it OK to branch from a tag?

Tags: svn

Simple question. Is this considered bad SVN practice? What are the negative consequences of branching from a tag?

Answer (score 4):

None that I am aware of. I think it is a perfectly okay thing to do. You do need to make sure you understand your needs for branching and ensure that you have a outlined a processes/timeline to merge changes back (if that is your goal). This post may help.

[Do you continue development in a branch or in the trunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646/do-you-continue-development-in-a-branch-or-in-the-trunk)

Answer (score 2):

First off, technically, it is possible and ok to do it.

It is going to depend on how you treat the tag. In general practice, tags are like pointers to a particular revision in trunk or branch that usually indicate, say, a release. So branching from tags is conceptually not an ok thing to do. What you should be doing is branch from the revision that the tag is pointing to and treat it as a branch where you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

From a technical point of view there is no problem at all. It really depends on your development process. I could envisage proceeding as you describe in a context where in general you only perform releases off trunk, and only under exceptional conditions you provide patches to a previous release. In this case creating a new branch for each release would just clutter your setup and it might be more reasonable to create such a branch only when it's needed.